# Automatic parameter and definition display for macro functions in SAS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

In `SAS EG` there is a neat feature that allows one to see the parameters of a macro function and its definitions when typing.

For example if I execute:

```
%macro test
(a /* this is a */
,b /* this is b */
);
%put a b;
%mend;
```

And then type `%test(`, a popup will show me "a : this is a" etc...

Unfortunately for some reason it seems to work only IF the macro function was defined in the current program (so basically in the only place where you don't really need it, as in that case it should be quite fresh in your mind).

- Is there any way to benefit from this feature in other programs and other process flows ?
- More importantly, how can I benefit from this feature for my stored compiled macros ?

Say for example I defined in another session :

```
options mstored sasmstore=mylib;
%macro test2
(c /* this is c */
,d /* this is d */
) / store source des='show c and d';
%put c d;
%mend;
```

I suppose a workaround would be to create a macro `%redefine_all` that would go through the catalog and execute every stored macro definition, but that's quite ugly and I'm not completely sure how I'd go at it...

Comment: Is this question also regarding autocall macros ?  Show sample code that creates a stored compiled macro that would then be available in a future EG session, but does not

Comment: Please see updated question. The macro IS available in other sessions, but this autodisplay feature is not triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a 'one of those things' thing.

The EG help "About the Program Editor" - "Using the autocomplete feature" states:

> The Program Editor can also read your current program and suggest
>   syntax for these program elements:
>
> macro variables that are defined by using the %LET statement or SYMPUT CALL routine
>
> macro routines that are defined by using the %MACRO statement
>
> data set names that are defined by using the DATA step
>   statement
>
> Note: The Program Editor does not automatically list macro
>   variables and routines that are defined outside of the current
>   document (for example, external macro programs, %include files, and
>   autoexec files).

Comment: I'll just add this to my list of things to rant about... I wonder what these guys are thinking sometimes. I think my workaround should be doable, I'll post it as an answer If I get to code it.

Comment: The standard macro functions autocomplete have pop up background(bluish) that is a different color than user/program editor pop up backgrounds (tannish), so it might be possible to discover and mimic the mechanism behind the standard popups.